# HTML/CSS - Smooth animation loop for infinite horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, css-animations, tailwind-css

I'm trying to implement an infinite keyframe animation for a background image for the hero section of a page by animating the translateX property.

It runs fine, however when it reaches the end of the animation it "jumps" back to the beginning without it being smooth.

I would like for it to smoothly go on without any "jumps."

```css
body,html{
 height:100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        slide: {
          '0%': { transform: "translateX(0)" },
          '100%': { transform: "translateX(-2509px)" },
        },
        slidemobile: {
          from: { transform: "translateX(0)" },
          to: { transform: "translateX(-375px)" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        slide: "slide 45s infinite linear",
        slidemobile: "slidemobile 20s infinite linear",
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>

<div id="img-background" class="bg-contain bg-repeat-x h-full animate-slidemobile w-[1125px] bg-[url('https://picsum.photos/200')] sm:animate-slide sm:w-[7527px]">
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Comment: I want the picture to scroll infinitely from left to right

Answer (score 1):

set `width & height to 100vw & 100vh;` & `overflow:hidden`

removed width class from html.7000px width why!?.
added class of `bg-no-repeat` which makes the images only once.
changing the image position to 100% to its right and -100% when animation reaches 100%.
shortened the animation timer

```css
body,html{
 height:100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script>
  tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        keyframes: {
          slide: {
            '0%': {
              transform: "translateX(100%)"
            },
            '100%': {
              transform: "translateX(-100%)"
            },
          },
          slidemobile: {
            from: {
              transform: "translateX(100)"
            },
            to: {
              transform: "translateX(-100)"
            },
          },
        },
        animation: {
          slide: "slide 5s infinite linear",
          slidemobile: "slidemobile 5s infinite linear",
        },
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<div id="img-background" class="bg-contain bg-no-repeat h-full animate-slidemobile bg-[url('https://picsum.photos/200')] sm:animate-slide ">
</div>
```